# Minimal condition and bounded gaps

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $x=(x_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}_{0}}$.
Let $X=\overline{\{T^{n}x\ :\ n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}\}}$, where $T$
is a shift map on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}_{0}}$. $T=T|_{X}$.

Question :$\forall x\in X$, $(X,T)$ is minimal 
if and only if any word $\omega=\omega_{1}\cdots\omega_{k}$ occurs
in $x$ with bounded gaps for any word $\omega$ occuring in $x$.

I tried to make the right statement into mathematical one, but it
is not easy. Can anyone help me?
(After editing) I know the definition of minimality is $X=\overline{\left\{ T^{n}x\ :\ n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}\right\} }$

Answer (score 1):

Simply: $X=\overline{\left\{ T^{n}x\ :\ n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}\right\} }$
if and only if every finite word occurs
in $x$. Gaps are irrelevant.

Comment: I guess my statement is correct. If you are right, how can I show the direction <- ?

Comment: It is completely immediate. Please clarify your question if it is a different one.

Comment: I edited. But I think nothing has been changed.

Comment: That's a different question; in this case a necessary and sufficient condition is that any word in $x$ occurs infinitely often in $x$. You don't need bounded gaps. Hint: think of the set $\{T^nx:n\ge m\}$.

Comment: Hmm I guess bounded gaps condition is necessary. Can I see your proof?

Comment: It is immediate, just try to think a bit. I have already replied, and then have I already replied after you changed the question. It is really not nice to change the question after being answered. Good luck.